# How to show data in view only if its value is > 0 in Angular

Tags: angular

I have some data from a web api coming in, I want to show the data only if its value is more than 0 so far what I am doing is not achieving this, which is:

example data structure:

```
result: Array(1)
0:
element: "xxxxx"
element_id: "xxxx"
name: "xxxxx"
etc etc etc
```

**component.ts**

```
receivedIncidentComments: any;

constructor(private service: nowService,
    private appComponent: AppComponent,
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.receivedIncidentComments = { created_on: '', value: ''}
  }

private getIncidentComments() {
  this.service.getIncidentComments(this.customer_id, this.sys_id).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Result - ', data);
    console.log('comments are received');
    this.receivedIncidentComments = data.result[0];
  })
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getIncident();
    this.getIncidentComments();
      })
  }
```

}

**service.ts**

```
 getIncidentComments(customerId, sys_id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.commentsApiUrl + "?customer_id=" + customerId + "&incident_id=" + sys_id)
       .pipe(
         catchError(this.handleError)
       );
   }
```

**html:**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="receivedIncidentComments.length > 0">
   <div class="information-text">
      <h5>Comments:</h5>
      <span class="text-gray">{{receivedIncidentComments.created_on}}</span><br />
      <span class="text-gray">{{receivedIncidentComments.value}}</span>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `*ngIf="data.length > 0"` check? what is `data`? Shouldn't you be using `receivedIncidentComments`?

Comment: Please update the question with the value of `data`

Comment: You're not assigning nothing to `data` property. Is `data` a public property of your component?

Comment: updated the code.

Comment: Why are you testing `data.length` in the `ngIf` condition? Try `<ng-container *ngIf="receivedIncidentComments.value > 0">` instead.

Comment: I have tried and updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

`<ng-container *ngIf="data.length > 0">`

with

`<ng-container *ngIf="receivedIncidentComments">`

Comment: could you post your function `getIncidentComments` in the service. we need to know what `data` returned from the service is.

Comment: are you getting any error with `<ng-container *ngIf="receivedIncidentComments.length > 0">` ?

I think you should get an error, because `receivedIncidentComments` is an object.

please try `*ngIf="receivedIncidentComments"` . If this does not work, could you show us a sample data of the comments object wich you recieve. For e.x the result of `console.log(data.result[0])`

Comment: I have updated the code with the structure of the data received. No errors

Comment: *ngIf="receivedIncidentComments" works. Can you add as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="receivedIncidentComments.length > 0">
   <div class="information-text">
      <h5>Comments:</h5>
      <span class="text-gray">{{receivedIncidentComments.created_on}}</span><br />
      <span class="text-gray">{{receivedIncidentComments.value}}</span>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some more info. Are you storing the incoming data in an instance variable ? receivedIncidentComments? in that case

```
*ngIf="receivedIncidentComments.length > 0"
```

your syntax of the *ngIf directive is correct. With can mean you are not constructing your boolean/logic statement with the correct members. Please share the entire TS and HTML file :)

Answer (score 0):

From your html structure it's clear that receivedIncidentComments is an object.
So To find the length of the object you can use the following

`Object.keys(receivedIncidentComments).length;`

Hope you can implement your own logic now.
You can simply store the object length in your component.ts file.
now for checking it in html 
you can use it like the following way.

`*ngIf = "your_variable > 0"`